# Way to show items where more than 5 decimal places occur?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to filter out some query results to where it only shows items with 6 decimal places. I don't need it to round up or add 0's to the answer, just filter out anything that is 5 decimal places or below. My current query looks like this: (ex. if item is 199.54215 i dont want to see it but if it is 145.253146 i need it returned)

```
select 
TRA_CODPLANTA,
TRA_WO,
TRA_IMASTER,
tra_codtipotransaccion,
tra_Correlativo,
TRA_INGRESOFECHA,
abs(tra_cantidadparcial) as QTY
from mw_tra_transaccion
where FLOOR (Tra_cantidadparcial*100000) !=tra_cantidadparcial*100000
and substring(tra_imaster,1,2) not in ('CP','SG','PI','MR')
and TRA_CODPLANTA not in ('4Q' , '5C' , '5V' , '8H' , '7W' , 'BD', 'DP')
AND tra_INGRESOFECHA > @from_date
and abs(tra_cantidadparcial) > 0.00000
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could convert to varchar, then do a SUBSTRING starting from the '.' and if the LEN is greater than 5, it is a number with at least 6 decimal places. OR you could take the LEN - the CHARINDEX of the period, which would probably be easier

Comment: That's what `where FLOOR (Tra_cantidadparcial*100000) !=tra_cantidadparcial*100000` already accomplishes, inasmuch as it considers non-zero digits only, and not literally the number of decimals used in storage. If it's not working, take a closer look at your source data (it won't necessarily work correctly for `FLOAT` data, for starters).

Comment: This should work with decimal type values: `where (tra_cantidadparcial * 1000000) mod 10 <> 0`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with ROUND, which seems to be the ideal function to use, since it remains in the realms of numbers.  If you have at most 5 decimal places, then rounding to 5 decimal places will leave the value unchanged.

```
create table #test (Tra_cantidadparcial decimal(20,10));

INSERT #test (Tra_cantidadparcial) VALUES (1),(99999.999999), (1.000001), (45.000001), (45.00001);

SELECT * FROM #test WHERE ROUND(Tra_cantidadparcial,5) != Tra_cantidadparcial;

drop table #test
```

Comment: I deleted my previous comment,  it works on smaller values as well. Nice solution. The OP  stated both  X=>6 and X=6. This would work for X>=6 but not X=6.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a conversion to `varchar` and using the `LEN` - the `CHARINDEX` of the decimal point, I'm not saying this is the best way, but you did ask for an example in syntax, so here you go:

```
 --Temp Decimal value holding up to 10 decimal places and 10 whole number places
DECLARE @temp DECIMAL(20, 10) = 123.4565432135


    --LEN returns an integer number of characters in the converted varchar
    --CHARINDEX returns the integer location of the decimal where it is found in the varchar
    --IF the number of characters left after subtracting the index of the decimal from the length of the varchar is greater than 5, 
    --you have more than 6 decimal places
IF LEN(CAST(@temp AS varchar(20))) - CHARINDEX('.', CAST(@temp AS varchar(20)), 0) > 5
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    SELECT 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database values are `VARCHAR` and exist in the DB like so:

```
100.123456
100.1
100.100
```

You can achieve this using a wildcard `LIKE` statement example

```
WHERE YOUR_COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

This will being anything containing a decimal place followed by AT LEAST 6 numeric values

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorthand way.

```
WHERE (LEN(CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, FieldName % 1)) - 2) >=5
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to `convert / cast` that column to a lower precision. Doing this would cause automatic rounding, but that would show you if it is 6 decimals or not based on the last digit. If the last digit of the converted value is 0, then it's false, otherwise it's true.

```
declare @table table (v decimal(11,10))
insert into @table
values
(1.123456789),
(1.123456),
(1.123),
(1.123405678)

select
    v
    ,cast(v as decimal(11,5))          --here, we are changing the value to have a precision of 5. Notice the rounding.
    ,right(cast(v as decimal(11,5)),1) --this is taking the last digit. If it's 0, we don't want it
from @table
```

Thus, your `where` clause would simply be.

`where right(cast(tra_cantidadparcial as decimal(11,5)),1) > 0`